# cx_Oracle not returning milliseconds for 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000

Tags: python, oracle, timestamp, cx-oracle

When I execute a SQL query using cx_Oracle and the results are `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000` the result returned is `1900-01-01 00:00:00` without the milliseconds.

If the result contains milliseconds that aren't all zeroes then I get the full timestamp including the milliseconds (i.e. `1900-01-01 00:00:00.123456`).

I've tried running `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF'` before running my other query but don't see any changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You and Nagh suspected correctly: it's a Python thing, but it's just a display thing. You're not losing timestamp precision.

The cx_Oracle Python library converts Oracle date types (Date, Timestamp..) into one of Python's date types, [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).

When a `datetime` object is printed out as a string, (ie, its `__str__()` method is called), it prints out in ISO 8601 format, using [`datetime.isoformat()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) - this method is where the decision not to print milliseconds when they are 0 is made (actually, a `datetime` has no millisecond field, it instead has microseconds, but same point).

However, this is just the *string representation* of the `datetime` object.  All of the time information is still there for you to use.

If you want to display milliseconds *all the time* you have to be explicit; try using [`strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
print now
# >>> 2013-11-28 15:34:47.223000
now = now.replace(microsecond=0) # Remove milliseconds
print now
# >>> 2013-11-28 15:34:47
print now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
# >>> 2013-11-28 15:34:47.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is on receiver side, someone optimizing numbers for you.

You can try to get this timestamp as string and check results

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF')
FROM dual;
```

Comment: If I run `select to_char(<field name>, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF')` it works perfectly but I'd rather not add that into the SQL query each time.

Comment: Well, then culprit on python side. Can\t help you much there. Not that familiar with python yet.